# Heroku NameError: name 'application' is not defined

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

I'm trying to deploy a django app to heroku and it keeps crashing. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
Here is my Procfile:

```
web: python app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT app.settings
```

And here is a snippet from my heroku logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 456, in spawn_worker
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
    self.callable = self.load()
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
NameError: name 'application' is not defined
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.13.4
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 250, in import_app
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:36148 (4)
2014-07-04 17:58:23 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue after doing several things, including upgrading my django install and changing my procfile to this:

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi --pythonpath app --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

It says application not found. well try changing gunicorn

> web: gunicorn YourProject.wsgi